# Neo4j 4, OGM ClassCastException: [Lscala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper; cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have a following Neo4j/Cypher/Spring Data Neo4j logic:

```
@Query("MATCH (parentD:Decision)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) WHERE id(parentD) = {parentDecisionId} RETURN childD AS decision, [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c:Criterion)<-[:VOTED_ON]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_FOR]->(childD) | {criterion: c,  weight: vg.avgVotesWeight} ] AS weightedCriteria, [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch:Characteristic)<-[:SET_ON]-(v:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(childD) | {characteristic: ch,  value: v.value} ] AS valuedCharacteristics")
List<DecisionMatrix> findAllDecisionMatrixs(@Param("parentDecisionId") Long parentDecisionId);
```

As a result this SDN 4 repository method retrieves a list of `DecisionMatrix`:

```
@QueryResult
public class DecisionMatrix {

    private Decision decision;

    private List<WeightedCriterion> weightedCriteria;

    private List<ValuedCharacteristic> valuedCharacteristics;

}
```

So far everything is working fine.

But due to a complex conditions I need to dynamically construct this query in the code and then to execute with `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session`:

```
Result queryResult = session.query(cypherQuery, parameters);
```

Once I get a result, I have to convert it to `List<DecisionMatrix>`

This is my converter:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<DecisionMatrix> convertResultToDecisionMatrixs(Result queryResult) {
        List<DecisionMatrix> decisionMatrixs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map<String, Object> result : queryResult) {
            DecisionMatrix decisionMatrix = new DecisionMatrix();
            decisionMatrix.setDecision((Decision) result.get(DecisionQueryBuilder.DECISION_VARIABLE_BASE_NAME));
            Object weightedCriteria = result.get("weightedCriteria");
            if (weightedCriteria != null) {
                decisionMatrix.setWeightedCriteria((List<WeightedCriterion>) weightedCriteria);
            }
            Object valuedCharacteristics = result.get("valuedCharacteristics");
            if (valuedCharacteristics != null) {
                decisionMatrix.setValuedCharacteristics((List<ValuedCharacteristic>) valuedCharacteristics);
            }

            decisionMatrixs.add(decisionMatrix);
        }
        return decisionMatrixs;
    }
```

but it fails right now on the following line:

```
decisionMatrix.setWeightedCriteria((List<WeightedCriterion>) weightedCriteria);
```

with a following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lscala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper; cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at com.example.domain.util.OGMUtils.convertResultToDecisionMatrixs(OGMUtils.java:43)
```

How to correctly convert my result to `List<DecisionMatrix>` (like SDN 4 repository method does)?

**UPDATED**

I have updated my converter:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<DecisionMatrix> convertResultToDecisionMatrixs(Result queryResult) {
        List<DecisionMatrix> decisionMatrixs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map<String, Object> result : queryResult) {
            DecisionMatrix decisionMatrix = new DecisionMatrix();
            decisionMatrix.setDecision((Decision) result.get(DecisionQueryBuilder.DECISION_VARIABLE_BASE_NAME));
            Object weightedCriteria = result.get("weightedCriteria");
            if (weightedCriteria != null) {
                List<WeightedCriterion> weightedCriterions = new LinkedList<>();
                MapWrapper<String, Object>[] weightedCriteriaArray = (MapWrapper<String, Object>[]) weightedCriteria;
                for (int i = 0; i < weightedCriteriaArray.length; i++) {
                    MapWrapper<String, Object> weightedCriteriaArrayElement = (MapWrapper<String, Object>) weightedCriteriaArray[i];
                    Double weight = (Double) weightedCriteriaArrayElement.get("weight");
                    Criterion criterion = (Criterion) weightedCriteriaArrayElement.get("criterion");
                    weightedCriterions.add(new WeightedCriterion(criterion, weight));
                }
                decisionMatrix.setWeightedCriteria(weightedCriterions);
            }
            Object valuedCharacteristics = result.get("valuedCharacteristics");
            if (valuedCharacteristics != null) {
                decisionMatrix.setValuedCharacteristics((List<ValuedCharacteristic>) valuedCharacteristics);
            }

            decisionMatrixs.add(decisionMatrix);
        }
        return decisionMatrixs;
    }
```

Not it is fails on the following line:

```
Criterion criterion = (Criterion) weightedCriteriaArrayElement.get("criterion");
```

with a following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy cannot be cast to com.example.domain.model.entity.decision.Criterion
```

How to solve this ? Is there any chance to reuse some logic from SDN 4 repository method internals in order to get a correct result ?

For example, AFAIK previously  we used

```
neo4jOperations.convert(nodeProxy, Criterion.class);
```

How it can be achieved today ?

Comment: Looks like "weightedCriteria" is some kind of map at that point? You might try debugging this, and inspecting the weightedCriteria object to see what's actually inside, and if there's any fields within to follow to reach the list you're after.

Comment: a `scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper` extends java.util.AbstractMap. You can try to use `values()`method to get a `Collection<T>`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have updated my question, now it is fail with java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy cannot be cast to com.example.domain.model.entity.decision.Criterion

Comment: This issue is a result of lack of support in SDN 4 for session.queryForObject for @QueryResult